# How to cancel support for ipad, and then upload the App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

If canceled up support for the ipad, iTunesConnect will reject this app, because this app before support for ipad.

steps to reproduce:
TARGETS - General - Deployment Info - Devices，The "universal" change "iphone",Then upload app

Error Screenshot：https://i.stack.imgur.com/na8sX.png

Comment: Maybe reading the article that they tell you to read would be a good place to start... [Technical Q&A QA1623](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: Apple does not allow you to remove iPad support from an app that previously had it.

You need to release your new iPhone-only version as a separate app.

Comment: How to release it？What are the consequences

Comment: You cannot release it as an update. You have to keep iPad support, or release it as a completely separate app. If you want to migrate any user data from the old app, that could get tricky. Also, if it's a paid app, existing users would need to pay again.